# Tar excluding ._ files

Tags: command-line, tar

Is there a way to create a tar file in OS X (Sierra, preferably) that does not include the ._ files?  I've tried using the --exclude option, but clearly don't know the right pattern to use.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Please add the command line used to the question

Comment: What filesystem are you one ._ files are not usually there on HFS+

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To suppress the creation of AppleDouble `._` files, use: `--disable-copyfile`

Example: `tar --disable-copyfile -cf file.tar file`

Comment: Wow. How terribly sneaky. Only becomes apparent they're in there when you go to extract. Even a listing with `-t` doesn't show them. And the option is not documented! Where do you discovery such sorcery for yourself?

Comment: bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3 on macOS 10.14.6 doesn't work anymore, sadly.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer didn't work on MacOS Monterey (V 12.4). The tar is bsdtar and the man page revealed that there's a separate option to be specified --no-mac-metadata

```
$ tar -czv --no-mac-metadata -f <file_name> <filelist>
```

Sequence of the options seem to matter as following command didn't give desired result:

```
$ tar --no-mac-metadata -czvf <file_name> <filelist>
```

Comment: To say that I am extremely disappointed to learn that a system tool has this borderline malicious "extension" enabled by default would be a serious understatement.

Answer (score 2):

In recent macOS versions `--disable-copyfile` option suggested in other answer *might* do nothing, but tar seems to honor `COPYFILE_DISABLE` environment variable. Use it like this:

```
COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar -cf file.tar file
```

Comment: RE: "In recent macOS versions `--disable-copyfile` option suggested in other answer does nothing," -- I find that statement to be false in  **macOS Catalina**. I just tested it and it works! (Doesn't work in **macOS Big Sur**)

Comment: @user3439894 well, `--disable-copyfile` doesn't work in Mojave, and I can't test other versions. Weird.

Comment: COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 works for me with macOS Sierra